# Notice: Array to string conversion in error when requesting data from a databse

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

I have looked around and I can't find the answer to my question.
I am trying to get a row from the database but it just gives me a notice saying:

Notice: Array to string conversion in /xampp/...

here's my code:

```
$sql6 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM replies WHERE thread_id = $thread_id");
    $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql6);
    $replies = '';
    if ($numRows < 1) {
        $replies =  "There are no replies yet, you can make the first!";
    } else {
        while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql6)) {
            $reply_content = $rows[5];
            $reply_username = $rows[7];
            $reply_date = $rows[8];
            $reply_author_id = [4];

            $sql9 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $reply_author_id");
            $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql); 
            if ($numRows < 1) {
                while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    $reply_user_fn = $rows['first_name'];
                    $reply_user_ln = $rows['last_name'];
                    $reply_user_id = $rows['id'];
                    $reply_user_pp = $rows['profile_pic'];
                    $reply_user_lvl = $rows['user_level'];
                    $reply_user_threads = $rows['threads'];
                    $reply_user_email = $rows['email'];


                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Please help me. I'm fairly new to PHP and I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Which line number does the error refer to?

Comment: is this line a typo?  `$reply_author_id = [4];`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to PHP as well, but shouldn't the code in your while comparison be

```
mysqli_fetch_array($sql6)
```

instead of

```
mysql_fetch_array($sql6)?
```

Comment: you are correct when it comes to security,but it wont give any error :)

Comment: Ah, I see.  I didn't know that.  I just saw that my code had the i and yours didn't, haha.

Answer (score 0):

**Typo**

```
 $sql9 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $reply_author_id");
 $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql); //here $sql will be $sql9
```

-----------------------------------------------^

```
 if ($numRows < 1) {
 while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {//here $sql will be $sql9
```

-------------------------------------------------------^

correct code:

```
 $sql9 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = $reply_author_id");
 $numRows = mysql_num_rows($sql9); //here $sql will be $sql9
 if ($numRows < 1) {
 while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql9)) {//here $sql will be $sql9
```

Comment: This got rid of the error, but now I get a new error which says that there is an error in my mysql syntax.